# Convert Column Values into comma separated str

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a table #f with the following data

| ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| V2 | 28 |
| V2 | 29 |
| V2 | 30 |

I would like my desired output to have

| ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| V2 | 28,29,30 |

How could I achieve this?

I've tried using the `STUFF` function but I get an error

> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

This is the code I have:

```
SELECT 
    #f.id, 
    number = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + f.id 
                    FROM #f f 
                    WHERE f.number = number 
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM
    #f
GROUP BY
    #f.id
```

Comment: You need to cast f.id to varchar

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution utilizing [string_agg](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
select ID
      ,string_agg(Number, ',') as Number
from t
group by ID
```

| ID | Number |
| --- | --- |
| V2 | 28,29,30 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d9bf6a3f37624e2b1e7fb09c4e057ff8&hide=1)